# Replace the Field Values in a Column Using Condition in SQL

Tags: sql, replace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

here's a sample table I am working with:

> ```
> ID      fruit 
> first   apl
> second  org
> third   bnna
> ```

I am trying to extract apl and bnna from the fruit column and then replace those with "apple" and "banana"

I tried:

```
select ID, fruit as replace(fruit, "apl", "apple"), fruit as replace(fruit, "bnna", "banana")
from tbl
where fruit = 'apl' or
      fruit = 'bnna'
```

I am looking for:

> ```
> ID      fruit 
> first   apple
> third   banana
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id,
 case
  when fruit='apl' then 'apple'
  when fruit='bnna' then 'banana'
  else fruit 
 end as fruit
from your_table
```

in case you need to update the data

```
update your_table set fruit='apple' where fruit='appl';
update your_table set fruit='banana' where fruit='bnna';
```